# How to write a regular expression to replace only the HOST name in the tnsnames.ora using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, tnsnames

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ora)))
```

I want to replace the HOST name with a new value using powershell, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operator:

```
$str = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ora)))'

$str -replace '(?<=\(HOST = )[^)]+', 'newhost'
```

Answer (score 1):

this uses the same `-replace` operator as used by `mklement0`, but uses a simpler pattern for those like myself who are regex-challenged. [*grin*]

```
$OldHost = 'myhost'
$NewHost = 'NewHostName'

$InStuff = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ora)))'

$OutStuff = $InStuff -replace "HOST = $OldHost", "HOST = $NewHost"

$InStuff
$OutStuff
```

output ...

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ora)))
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NewHostName)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ora)))
```